# How can i Run the multiple jmx file in one docker image and all of result should show in single place

Tags: docker, jmeter, docker-compose, jmeter-4.0

How can I Run the multiple JMX files in one docker image and all of the result should show in single place.

Without Taurus is this possible?
or 
Can I run the all JMX files one by one in docker with the help of dynamic name of JMX files

I am using Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can run several JMX files at the same time using i.e. [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) program, the syntax would be something like:

```
parallel ::: "./jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result.jtl" "./jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result.jtl"
```

Another option is using different result files for each .jmx script and once test is finished combine them using [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/). You can install Merge Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Using this line in docker image

*CMD ./bin/jmeter -n -t ./bin/test1.jmx -l ./bin/result.jtl -e -o ./bin/result_html*